# How can I add a background image under a base64 generated image using PHP?

Tags: php

This works:

```
$img = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode(str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $image)));

$width = imagesx($img);
$height = imagesy($img);
$output = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$white = imagecolorallocate($output,  255, 255, 255);
imagefilledrectangle($output, 0, 0, $width, $height, $white);
imagecopy($output, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);
imagejpeg($output, './'.$filename);
echo $filename;
```

But I want to add a background image under this image, what I searched maybe using `imagecreatefromjpeg("bg.png")` but how can I achieve?

Comment: do you mean watermark?

Comment: @Rafael No, I want the front is my base64 image like the code, the back is the background `bg.png` image, they are transparent together into one image.

Comment: @Rafael The image size should be same as background image : `bg.png`

Answer (score 0):

- bg image
- new image
- merge them together

Here is a example how to use it:

http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples.merged-watermark.php

Comment: The image size should be same as background image : `bg.png`